# Making distinct data.frame with cbind and loop function

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I’m generating multiple datatable with cbind and loop function.

Let's suppose that I have two data.frame. Each data.frame is 100*10.

```
first<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,100,rep=TRUE)))
second<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(2:10,100,rep=TRUE)))
```

The each column of `second` data.frame is binded with `first` data.frame, generating ten 100*11 data.frame (first+one column of `second` data.frame).

So, I created loop function like this.

```
for (i in 1:10){
cbind(first,second[,i])}
```

This function has two problems.

First. after running it, nothing happened. Only this syntax appeared in console window.

```
> for (i in 1:10){
+ ti<-cbind(first,second[,i])}
```

Second, I want to save the outcome in each distinct objects, like `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, ...., `t10`. So, I ran this code.

```
for (i in 1:10){
ti<-cbind(first,second[,i])}
```

However, as you might think, it save the results in '`ti`' objects repeatedly. So, the `ti` object is `first` data frame + 10th column of `second` data.frame.

How to make 10 distinct objects, like `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4` ..., `t10`?

*Additional question : In fact, the `second` data.frame in real work is more than 100 columns. So, the producted objects are `t1`, `t2`, .... `t100`, .... and continued. Is there a way to save these objects organized?

*Additional question to Akrun's answer

Really thanks to your help. It worked!

However, there is a new problem. What I want to do with results was a bit complicate.

Let's take a example with `t1` obejct in `lst1` list. It takes two steps.

I want to excute `data.matrix` function with `t1` object, and put the outcome of `data.matrix` into `predict` function. (Due to its functional reason, the original function of `predict` only able to calculate `data.matrix`)

If it were `data.frame`, I would ran

`data.matrix(t1)
predict(orginalfunction,newx=t1,matrix=TRUE)`

However, after reading your answer, I think it is right to use `lapply` with list. `data.frame` is too messy.

But, how can I apply the `data.matrix` function to each objects of list and put it into `predict` function?

Comment: The usual answer is to not make `t1`-to-`tN` objects, and instead create a list, something like - `all_t <- Map(cbind, list(first), X11=second)` . Then you can easily enough loop over `all_t` as a `list` if you need to make changes to every object all at once.

Comment: Along that line ... iteratively building a list by adding "so many rows" with each step might work "okay" for a while, but because it makes a copy of all data with each call to `cbind`, it scales horribly and will eventually take a lot longer than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `lapply`.  Loop through the columnss of 'second', and `cbind` to create a new column in 'first', set the names of the `list` with the names of choice.  As @thelatemail mentioned (and agree totally with that), it is better not to create objects in the global env, instead keep, store, process, and write from the `list` itself using tools such as `lapply/sapply/vapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(second, function(x) cbind(first, newcol = x))
names(lst1) <- paste0("t", seq_along(lst1))
```

As it is a `list`, we can use `lapply` to loop through the list

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) predict(originalfunction, newx = x, matrix = TRUE))
```

Comment: It worked. I really thanks to your answer. However, there is a new problem. I add explanation about it under this answer. Would you answer it?

Comment: @ESKim  Not clear about the orignalfunction, please check my updated answer

Comment: Oh, my question was deleted due to the community rule. But, it worked! I really appreciate that. `apply` function is really useful.

Comment: @ESKim  I think it got deleted bcz you were supposed to edit the question and update it there.  Glad that my updated solution is useful